# How to fetch value usin VBS script for the below?

Tags: vbscript

```
<input type="text" value="Phone" name="Phone" />
```

I can't set using Id as like below. I dont have rights to change the tag as well. Is ther any option using name value inorder to set value?

```
Set Helem=IE.document.getElementByValue("Phone")
Helem.Value = "1234565678"
```

Comment: <input type="text"  value="Phone" name="Phone"  this is my html element

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `IE` in your sample is some instance of internet explorer or Shell.Application, use the following sintax

```
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementsByName("Phone")
```

And it will not return a reference to the element, but a HTMLCollection of elements. From your code, it can be, more or less, handled as as array. Assuming there is only one element with that name, reference to it will be in `Helem(0)`